# How do I program the forward and backward buttons for a browser in the current version of Livecode using the browser widget for desktop applications

Tags: javascript, browser, livecode

I have looked high and low for this answer to what I believe is a simple thing.

I am programming a web browser using Livecode (current version with business license) and am having a terrible time trying to get a back button and forward button to work with the built in Browser widget.

This is for a desktop application and not (currently) for a mobile version.  It seems the mobile version would be insanely easy but does not work for desktop.

After doing extensive research, the only ideas I found were to utilize a javascript command in Livecode but my particular problem was nowhere to be found.

Here is the code I came up with for trying to go forward a website in the history:

```
set the javascriptHandlers of widget "Browser" to "javascript:history.go(+1)"
```

Backwards in the history would be (-1).

It does not work.  Does anyone have any advice on how to execute the javascript command inside of Livecode?

I was told by Livecode support to use go in widget commands but I have not found one shred of documentation on this - and nothing specifically for a web browser in a Livecode desktop application that is any more current than 2017.

Thank you for your help.

Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the script of the back button to

```
go back in Widget "browser"
```

and the script of the forward to

```
go forward in widget "browser"
```

Comment: Thank you.  Livecode support gave me that an hour ago, but thank you for answering it.  It seems so easy but there is no documentation save for their dictionary which I find hard to read or use.

Comment: Does anyone know how to STOP a webpage from loading.  Not just putting empty into the URL?